# Delete an empty folder right after deletion of all the images inside

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm writing a function to delete a user in my application, which is powered by NodeJS Mongoose and Cloudinary, and I want to erase all the pictures the user has uploaded into its personal folder and the folder itself. This is the code I wrote to delete a single user (Please note that the name of the user is the name of its folder):

```
module.exports = (id, callback) => {
    User.findByIdAndDelete(id, function (err, user) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err);

        if (!user)
            return callback(null, null);


        cloudinary.api.delete_resources_by_prefix(`${user.username}/`, function (err) {
            if (err && err.http_code !== 404) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            cloudinary.api.delete_folder(`${user.username}`, function (error, result) {
                if (error && error.http_code !== 404) {
                    return callback(error);
                }
                return callback(null, `${user.username}`);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

The issue is when I run it that the second API request replies with this error:

```
{ message: 'Folder is not empty', http_code: 400 }
```

This is obviously not true because I have deleted the files in the API call above. I checked also the correct behavior of the first call by the UI of cloudinary and everything works right except for the last call. So what I'm asking is:

1. There's an undocumented method to delete a folder and its content in one single call?
2. If not, how can I do that without getting this error?
3. There's any workaround that does not involve folders? I have watched tags but I don't know if it could result in a performance degrade.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have backup enable? can you search in the media library for deleted images?
You can delete the folder by using delete by prefix (folder name) in the [bulk delete option](https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/bulk_delete/new).
Here is a script to delete the empty folders:

```
to_delete=[]
res = cloudinary.api.subfolders("Top Folder")
for resource in res['folders']:
    to_delete.append(resource['path'])
    continue

i = 0
while i < len(to_delete):
    print(to_delete[i])
    cloudinary.api.delete_folder(to_delete[i])
    i += 1
```

If you need help, you can also contact us at support@cloudinary.com with your cloud name and we can find more informations.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply,  yes I have backup enabled, is it a problem? I don't think I can search in the media library but I'm not sure about this last one. As you can see from my code I already know that the folder of the user to delete is empty. Can you explain to me why do I have to also perform a subfolder check?

Answer (score 0):

If the backup is enabled it not considered as an empty folder.
You can open a ticket at support@cloudinary.com and we can check it out.